# Grails command object inheritance

Tags: java, grails, inheritance, model-view-controller, groovy

In my project I use abstract controller to wrap some basic rest stuff.

lets say we have a base domain class: `abstract class Entity`. And a base controller:

```
abstract class CrudController<
    Domain extends Entity, 
    DTO extends Command<Domain>,
    Service extends CrudService<Domain>> {

    //...//

    def insert(DTO dto) { 
        //..// 
    }

    //...//

}

class Command<Domain extends Entity> {

}
```

and then we have our implementations:

```
SomeController extends CrudController<SomeDomain,SomeCommand,SomeService> 
SomeCommand extends Command<SomeDomain>
SomeDomain extends Entity
```

The code compile without complaining, but insert method always receives null. Am I on the right track? How can I make this work?

**UPDATE**

It seems that insert method receives `Command` instead of `SomeCommand` instance.

Comment: so you think, that the data binding is not working there?  can you do a quick override of the method in your concrete instance there and see if this fills the object?  or how can you be sure, that there is no error already in an earlier stage (e.g. submitted data)?

Comment: @cfrick I've checked it, if you pass `SomeCommand` to `SomeController` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create explicit constructor with the super properties for the command class. It worked for me:

```java
ClassConstructor() {
    this.propOne = super.propOne
    this.propTwo = super.propTwo
}
```